# how can i update and modify my arrays with userinput

Tags: c#, arrays

so I've asked this question before but couldn't seem to get anywhere so i thought i'd ask again and maybe someone can help now that I've gotten another part of my code working. so i need to know how i can update and delete an entry. i would like to clarify that i want to do this through only user input.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PlayerSystem6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //The MAXPLAYERS constant is the physical table size
            const Int32 MAXPLAYERS = 23;

            //Declare the player tables
            Int32[] playerNumbers = new Int32[MAXPLAYERS];
            String[] playerLastNames = new String[MAXPLAYERS];
            Int32[] playerPoints = new Int32[MAXPLAYERS];

            //Keep track of the actual number of players (i.e. logical table size)
            Int32 playerCount = 0;

            //Main Driver
            char menuItem;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the player system...\n");
            menuItem = GetMenuItem();
            while (menuItem != 'X')
            {
                ProcessMenuItem(menuItem, playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, ref playerCount, MAXPLAYERS);
                menuItem = GetMenuItem();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nThank you, goodbye");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //Returns either a 'C', 'R', 'U', 'D', 'L', or 'X' to the caller
        static char GetMenuItem()
        {
            char menuItem;
            DisplayMenu();
            menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            while (menuItem != 'C' && menuItem != 'R' //JG
                && menuItem != 'L' && menuItem != 'X' && menuItem != 'U')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError - Invalid menu item");
                DisplayMenu();
                menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            }
            return menuItem;
        }

        static void DisplayMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease pick an item:");
            Console.WriteLine("C - Create Player");
            Console.WriteLine("R - Retrieve Player");
            Console.WriteLine("U - Update Player");
            Console.WriteLine("D - Delete Player");
            Console.WriteLine("L - List Players");
            Console.WriteLine("X - Exit");
        }

        //Routes to the appropriate process routine based on the user menu choice
        static void ProcessMenuItem(Char menuItem, Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastNames,
            Int32[] playerPoints, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            switch (menuItem)
            {
                case 'C':
                    ProcessCreate(playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, ref playerCount, MAXPLAYERS);
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    ProcessList(playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, playerCount);
                    break;
                case 'R': //JG
                    ProcessRetrieve(playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, ref playerCount, MAXPLAYERS);
                    break;
                case 'U':
                    ProcessUpdate(playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, playerCount, MAXPLAYERS);
                    break;

            }
        }

        //Creates a player in the tables if the array is not already full and the name is not a duplicate
        static void ProcessCreate(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastNames,
            Int32[] playerPoints, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            Int32 number, points;
            String lastName;
            if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
            {
                number = GetPositiveInteger("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's number");
                if (GetPlayerIndex(number, playerNumbers, playerCount) == -1)
                {
                    lastName = GetString("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's last name");
                    points = GetPositiveInteger("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's points");
                    InsertPlayer(number, lastName, points, playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, ref playerCount);
                    Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: Number - {0}, Name - {1}, Points - {2}, created successfully", number, lastName, points);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player number already exists");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player roster is already full");

        }

        //Inserts the player at the correct location in the tables based on order of 
        //ascending player number. Unless the insert location is at the end, this 
        //requires shifting existing players down in order to make room 
        static void InsertPlayer(Int32 number, String lastName, Int32 points,
            Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastNames, Int32[] playerPoints,
            ref Int32 playerCount)
        {
            /* PUTS DATA IN NEXT AVALIABLE SLOT
            playerNumbers[playerCount] = number;
            playerLastNames[playerCount] = lastName;
            playerPoints[playerCount] = points;
            playerCount++;
            */

            // PUTS DATA IN PLAYER ASECENDING ORDER
            Int32 insertIndex, shiftCount;
            insertIndex = GetInsertIndex(number, playerNumbers, playerCount);
            for (shiftCount = playerCount; shiftCount > insertIndex; shiftCount--)
            {
                playerNumbers[shiftCount] = playerNumbers[shiftCount - 1];
                playerLastNames[shiftCount] = playerLastNames[shiftCount - 1];
                playerPoints[shiftCount] = playerPoints[shiftCount - 1];
            }
            playerNumbers[insertIndex] = number;
            playerLastNames[insertIndex] = lastName;
            playerPoints[insertIndex] = points;
            playerCount++;

        }
        //Returns the index of the first player number in the table that is greater
        //than the player number to be inserted
        static Int32 GetInsertIndex(Int32 playerNumber, Int32[] playerNumbers,
            Int32 playerCount)
        {
            Int32 index = 0;
            bool found = false;
            while (index < playerCount && found == false)
                if (playerNumbers[index] > playerNumber)
                    found = true;
                else
                    index++;
            return index;
        }

        //Returns the index of the player number in the table 
        //or -1 if the number is not found
        static Int32 GetPlayerIndex(Int32 playerNumber,
            Int32[] playerNumbers, Int32 playerCount)
        {
            Int32 index = 0;
            bool found = false;
            while (index < playerCount && found == false)
                if (playerNumbers[index] == playerNumber)
                    found = true;
                else
                    index++;
            if (found == false)
                index = -1;
            return index;
        }

        //Lists the players in the tables
        static void ProcessList(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastNames,
            Int32[] playerPoints, Int32 playerCount)
        {

            if (playerCount > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n{0,7}   {1,-25}{2,6}\n", "Number", "Last Name", "Points");
                for (Int32 player = 0; player < playerCount; player++)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,7}   {1,-25}{2,6}", playerNumbers[player], playerLastNames[player], playerPoints[player]);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nList Players: the roster is empty");
        }

        //Returns a positive integer
        static Int32 GetPositiveInteger(String prompt)
        {
            Int32 n;
            Console.WriteLine(prompt);
            n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (n < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError: enter positive value");
                Console.WriteLine(prompt);
                n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            return n;
        }

        //Returns a non-empty string
        static String GetString(String prompt)
        {
            String returnString;
            Console.WriteLine(prompt);
            returnString = Console.ReadLine();
            while (returnString == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError: must enter keyboard data");
                Console.WriteLine(prompt);
                returnString = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            return returnString;
        }
        // retrieve single value from an array

        //static void ProcessRetrieve(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastNames
        //, Int32[] playerPoints, Int32 playerCount)
        //{

        //}
```

So right here i begin the process of retrieving the a single entry which works and is a function that i can reuse by modifying to work with the next two functions.

```
        static void ProcessRetrieve(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastNames,
            Int32[] playerPoints, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            int player;// Player number to find
            int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array
            if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
            {
                player = GetPositiveInteger("\nRetrieve Player: please enter the player's number"); //JG I used the same mechanism when you are creating the record, when you create yu check if it exists
                /** If it exists you say record exists in this case I said display the existing record**/
                playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(player, playerNumbers, playerCount);
                if (playerindex != -1)// !-1 means Does not exist JG
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("{0,7}   {1,-25}{2,6}", playerNumbers[playerindex], playerLastNames[playerindex], playerPoints[playerindex]);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nRetrieve Player: the player number does not exists");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nRetrieve Player: the player does not exist in the roster");
        }
```

Now here is where i'm having difficulty, how do i make this code update instead of retrieve i'm absolutely lost here and i've looked into many articles and only found how to change the array through the code instead of with user input

```
        static void ProcessUpdate(Int32[] playerNumbers,
        string[] playerLastnames, Int32[] playerpoints, Int32 playerCounts, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            int player;// Player number to find
            int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array
            if (playerCounts < MAXPLAYERS || playerCounts == MAXPLAYERS)
            {
                player = GetPositiveInteger("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's number");
                playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(player, playerNumbers, playerCounts);
                if (playerindex != -1)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("{0,7}   {1,-25}{2,6}", playerNumbers[playerindex], playerLastnames[playerindex], playerpoints[playerindex]);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: the player number does not exists");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: the player does not exist in the roster");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: could you point to the code that isn't working? there's too much code to understand what you require

Comment: In GetMenuItem() you're parsing a char from a string. Console also has Console.ReadKey() for this so the user can never enter more than 1 char.

Comment: I've edited my code to seperate my problem areas i've done alot of research and found how to retrieve but have had no such luck in doing the same for update and delete, but for delete i know that i just need to replace the value with spaces so all i really need to know is how to update the values through user input.

Comment: Currently, you're keeping track of all your data through seperate lists (playernumbers, points). Because you have no way to identify which points are for which player you don't know what to update? Using a class to create a player object you could keep track of a list of players (list of player) instead of seperate arrays. This way you'll find it easier to search for a player and add/substract points per player.

Comment: my lab specs require me to use 3 seperate arrays one for the playerLastNames one for playerPoints and one for playerNumber, what i need to be able to do is modify all three of those arrays when the user goes into the update function, inorder to identify which player needs to be modified it has to ask for the player number when the number is inputted the program will determine wether it is a valid number or not if it's valid it'll bring up the player associated with that player number and ask for a new number new lastname and new points and then update them.

Comment: I don't understand why you have a problem. Asking the user to input data of the player to update is not the problem (as evidenced by your ProcessCreate method). Getting an array index according to the player number cannot really be your problem either (as evidenced by your GetPlayerIndex method). Writing the data to the array elements at position specified by "playerIndex" cannot be the problem (as evidenced by your method InsertPlayer). I am lost in the woods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you already have the building blocks required to create your update function. Let's take a look at what these are.

1. You will have to ask for the player number first. You have this already implemented in your ProcessUpdate method.

   ```
           player = GetPositiveInteger("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's number");
   ```
2. You will have to find the array index matching the player number. This you have also already implemented in your ProcessUpdate method.

   ```
           playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(player, playerNumbers, playerCounts);
   ```
3. You will need to ask the user for the new player data. You have this already implemented in the ProcessCreate method - and only the strings need to be altered to clarify that we now ask for updated data.

   ```
               lastName = GetString("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's updated last name");
               points = GetPositiveInteger("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's updated points");
   ```
4. Lastly, you will have to put the data you just got from the user into the arrays. You have implemented this already in InsertPlayer - we just pay attention to use the correct variable names here.

   ```
       playerLastNames[playerindex] = lastName;
       playerPoints[playerindex] = points;
   ```

Putting this all together (including variable declarations and sanity checks), your ProcessUpdate method should look like this:

```
    static void ProcessUpdate(Int32[] playerNumbers,
    string[] playerLastnames, Int32[] playerpoints, Int32 playerCounts, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
    {
        int player;// Player number to find
        int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array

        String lastName;
        int points;

        if (playerCounts < MAXPLAYERS || playerCounts == MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            player = GetPositiveInteger("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's number");
            playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(player, playerNumbers, playerCounts);
            if (playerindex != -1)
            {
                lastName = GetString("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's updated last name");
                points = GetPositiveInteger("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's updated points");

                playerLastNames[playerindex] = lastName;
                playerPoints[playerindex] = points;

            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: the player number does not exists");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: the player does not exist in the roster");
        }
    }
```

Generally speaking, the structure of your program is not an example of how to do it right (sorry). However, i don't know about your programming course. Did your course already cover struct's, objects (object-oriented programming), or other "advanced" data types like dictionaries, or will these be future topics? I know that you are required to use 3 arrays, but already with the help of struct's alone you could clean-up your code significantly while still meeting the requirements.

Comment: No we haven't covered proper structuring just yet, the professor believes that it's nessary to learn through our imporper coding before he teaches us how to use classes to clean up our code and what not, but thank you for your help i knew i was on the right track just wasn't sure how to get the new data into my array

Answer (score 0):

Below I wrote an example on how to update a player's score and name through user input.
By keeping the index of the nums, names and points in the same index per player we can keep track of them.

```
// Make sure the indexes of the arrays are aligned with the player array 
// (to keep track which points are for which player)
int[] playerNums = new int[10];
string[] playerNames = new string[10];
int[] playerPoints = new int[10];

// We now add the user here (you do it somewhere from user input)
playerNums[0] = 1;
playerNames[0] = "Tim";
playerPoints[0] = 10;

char key = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;
if (char.IsDigit(key))
{
    // We get the number from the char.
    int inputNum = int.Parse(key.ToString());

    // We make sure the user isn't giving an index past the length of our arrays
    // (which are 10 in size).
    if (inputNum > -1 && inputNum < playerNums.Length - 1)
    {
        playerNames[inputNum] = "John"; // Tim now becomes John.
        playerPoints[inputNum] += 5; // Increase John's score.
    }
}
```

Tell me if this was the answer you were looking for.

Comment: i understand what you're doing here but it's not exactly what i mean i want to be able to modify the players that were entred by the user through the "create player" function i created

Comment: @Shahze123, by any chance, could it be that you have difficulties in understanding the basics of C#? To know this would help to understand your problem.

Comment: @elgonzo that would be correct i'm a beginner programming student and am doing this for an assignment, i understand quite a bit of it but some concepts escape me.

Comment: It might help you starting a new project with just 1 array and adding/updating it so you can have a clearer understanding of how you can work with arrays in C#.

Comment: @Measuring i've worked with with one array at a time but was never taught how to do updates, retrival of one element or deletion, which is why i'm here i've got a basic understanding and enough to know that the logic i used for ProcessRetrieve can be modified to do updates and deletions but in the case of delete i can just force the program to change the values of the selected elements into blank spaces so they won't show up anymore

Comment: I see. Well like you said, you can't remove items from an array. You just assign it's default value. Though you shouldn't build a castle if you don't know how to set the fundamentals right yet. Start small, start clear (readable code) and look for things to make your life easier (build-in functions and classes you could use).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of array use Dictionary as below, so that you need not maintain any index for all the arrays and if you want to search for a particular element it is very easy. And Player number is the key for every player info, you can chose the key as anything you want. 
Refer below links for more details
http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

namespace Player
{
    class Program
    {

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, PlayerInfo> info = new Dictionary<string, PlayerInfo>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Player Number");
            string playerNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            info.Add(playerNumber, new PlayerInfo());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Player Name");
            info[playerNumber].PlayerName = Console.ReadLine(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Player Points");
            info[playerNumber].points = Console.ReadLine(); 
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the player number to be deleted");
        string playerNumberToDelete = Console.ReadLine();
        info.Remove(playerNumberToDelete);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a player number to update");
        string playerNumberToUpdate = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Player Name");
        info[playerNumberToUpdate].PlayerName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Player Points");
        info[playerNumberToUpdate].points = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter player number dispaly deatils");
        string playerNumberToDisplay = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Name " + info[playerNumberToDisplay].PlayerName);
        Console.WriteLine("Points " + info[playerNumberToDisplay].points);
    }
}
class PlayerInfo
{
    public string PlayerName;
    public string points;
}
```

}

Comment: OP must use 3 arrays per his assignment.

Comment: @Kumareshan, as my question states i am required to use three arrays, sadly i'm unable to get the update to work still but retrieve is working without issue, does anyone know how to modify it i've gone through every line of my own code to see if i could do it but still nothing i was hoping my `ProcessCreate` would would have something but it's the exact same as my retrieve so it wont work.

Comment: Your ProcessUpdate shall look below

Answer (score 0):

Your ProcessUpdate shall look as below

```
     static void ProcessUpdate(Int32[] playerNumbers, string[] playerLastnames, Int32[] playerpoints, Int32 playerCounts, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            int player;// Player number to find
            int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array
            if (playerCounts <= MAXPLAYERS)
            {
                player = GetPositiveInteger("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's number");
                playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(player, playerNumbers, playerCounts);
                if (playerindex != -1)
                {
                    string lastName = GetString("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's last name");
                    int points = GetPositiveInteger("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's points");
                    playerLastnames[playerindex] = lastName;
                    playerpoints[playerindex] = points;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,7}   {1,-25}{2,6}", playerNumbers[playerindex], playerLastnames[playerindex], playerpoints[playerindex]);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: the player number does not exists");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: the player does not exist in the roster");
        }
```